# Working with environment variables in Makefiles on Windows

Tags: windows, eclipse, makefile

I have written a makefile. This makefile is to be checked into SVN. I used environment variables for my project directory path so that different computers can run the makefile without having to make changes to it.

for example: `PRJ_ROOT_DIR := $(REF_DIR)/projectName/trunk/Temp`
where environment variable `REF_DIR` is `C:/Users/myName/Desktop`.

However, by just building the project, makefile automatically changed to:
`PRJ_ROOT_DIR := C:/Users/myName/Desktop/projectName/trunk/Temp`

This shows up in SVN that makefile has been modified.

How do I do it so that makefile remains as
`PRJ_ROOT_DIR := $(REF_DIR)/projectName/trunk/Temp`? Where changes is done in the background and not showed up on the built makefile so that SVN will not detect the change?

Comment: Does the makefile have a rule for modifying itself? And what does Eclipse have to do with this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer; the `makefile` is auto-generated. Hence, modifying the generated makefile does not help.

I tagged eclipse because compilation is done in eclipse environment. I thought that there may be some settings that I may need to change when in that environment.